# How to match list elements individually against AND / ALL / multiple patterns in Python - list(), re.match()?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list and I want only the list elements that match ALL patterns in the regex. I can't seem to figure this out, I'm new to this and thank you for your help.

The resulting print/list should only be one instance of 'panic'

```
import re

green = ['.a...', 'p....', '...i.']

wordlist = ['names', 'panic', 'again', '.a...']

for value in wordlist:
    for pattern in green:
        #print(value, pattern)
        if re.match(pattern, value):
            print(value)
#=>
names
panic
panic
panic
again
.a...
```

Comment: Look for one that does not match. If successful - then "not all" is proven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small modification of your code:

```
import re

green = ['.a...', 'p....', '...i.']

wordlist = ['names', 'panic', 'again', '.a...']

for value in wordlist:
    for pattern in green:
        if not re.match(pattern, value):
            break
    else:
        print(value)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) for the `for/else` construct.

---

Different approach

```
hits = (v for v in wordlist if all(re.match(pattern, v) for pattern in green))
for h in hits:
    print(h)
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I can use inverse logic to create the all() boolean outcome. Thanks for the second approach as well, that is what I was trying to use originally.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use function **all**

```
import re

patterns = ("regex1", "regex2", "regex3")
wordlist = ("word1", "word2", "word3")

for word in wordlist:
    if all(re.match(pattern, word) for pattern in patterns):
        print(word)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it was already submitted by another.