# InvalidSessionIdException while Selenium driver is not closed

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following snippet of my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

for _ in range(10):
    try:
       driver.get(URL)
       wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='sr-match-default__status-pre']")))
       driver.close()
        # do something
    except TimeoutException:
        time.sleep(300)
        continue
else:
    driver.close()
```

This yields a `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException` but I don't know why.

When I look at the error, the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException) say the following:

> Occurs if the given session id is not in the list of active sessions,
> meaning the session either does not exist or that it’s not active.

This is not the case with my code. Earlier in my script / code I define and use the `driver` successfully before closing it. In addition, the `driver` is able to retrieve the URL without ay problems. Please advice

The full error log looks as follows:

```
  File "/scheduler.py", line 24, in get_new_matches
    driver.get(URL)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000102fe7159 chromedriver + 5120345
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000102f74b13 chromedriver + 4651795
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000102b64d1f chromedriver + 392479
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000102b8ce94 chromedriver + 556692
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000102bb7abc chromedriver + 731836
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000102bb5885 chromedriver + 723077
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000102bb5127 chromedriver + 721191
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000102b3d7da chromedriver + 231386
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000102fa438d chromedriver + 4846477
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000102fbe21c chromedriver + 4952604
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000102fc3a12 chromedriver + 4975122
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102fbeb4a chromedriver + 4954954
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102f995b0 chromedriver + 4801968
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102b3c8ae chromedriver + 227502
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff6757dcc9 start + 1
15  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `break` statement in the `for`, without it the code behaves as the loop wasn't successful and executes the `else` block where you close the `driver` for a second time. See [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops) for more detailed explanation.

Adding `break` statement at the end of the `try` block should solve the issue.