# Why is tabbed else and else give different answer?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

What's the difference betwen this:

```
print("Prime numbers between 0 and", num)
for x in range(0, num+1):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(x)
```

and this:

```
print("Prime numbers between 0 and", num)
for x in range(0, num+1):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
            print(x)
```

Can i have some answer? It gives very different answer and i don't get why? Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: In one case it is relative to the `for`, in the other case relative to the `if`

Comment: I think your second print should be indented.

Comment: indendation of the print

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Indentation is very important in python. It does not matter if you use tabs or spaces, but the amount of indentation determines scope.

Comment: From [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement): *When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence is empty or an iterator raises a StopIteration exception), the suite in the else clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.*

Answer (score 0):

Python lets you attach an `else` clause to a `for` loop. It's a bit unusual, it's the only language I can think of that allows that.

The `else`'s body will get called if the `for` loop completes "normally", rather than a call to `break`.

It might be useful to flip the question: Why would you expect the `else` on a `for` to behave the same way as on `if (x % i) == 0`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23748240/1126841 as well, which links to some history behind `for...else`.