# Why can two sets of the same code produce two different outputs?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm making code that can determine whether the number entered by the user is prime or not. But I kept running into a bug that oddly enough, my friend's code didn't, even though our codes was the same down to the letter.

```
#my friend's
num = int(input())

if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

```
#mine
num = int(input())

if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num,"is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
            break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
    print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

If I enter 121 to my friend's code, the output will be:

```
121
121 is not a prime number
11 times 11 is 121
```

But if I enter 121 to my code, the output will be:

```
121
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is a prime number
121 is not a prime number
11 times 11 is 121
```

What's wrong with mine?

Comment: Did you manage to understand the difference in the code?

Comment: @FirefightingPhysicist yes, I did!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your indentation. Your friends code does `for` or `else`, your code does `if` or `else`. Read more about why `else` can be used with `for` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops).

```
#your friend's
...
   for i in range(2,num): 
       if ...
   else: # enters when `for` loop breaks
       ...
   
#you
...
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            ...
        else: # enters when `if` returns false
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indentation issue with your code.

```
#my friend's
num = int(input())

if num > 1:
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
       else:
           print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Here i

```
#mine
num = int(input())

if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num,"is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
            break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")
else:
    print(num,"is not a prime number")
```