# How does the else condition work after a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

How does the `else:` condition work after a for loop in Python? I thought that `else` can work only after an `if` condition.

```
for i in range(5):
     print(i)
else:
    print("done")
```

I don't know how or why it works.

Comment: Check this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 4):

The `else` clause of a `for` loop is executed if the loop terminates because the iterator is exhausted, i.e., if a `break` statement is not used to exit the loop. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> When the iterator is exhausted, the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.
>
> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite. A `continue` statement executed in the first suite skips the rest of the suite and continues with the next item, or with the `else` clause if there is no next item.

Compare

```
for i in range(5):
    pass
else:
    print("Iterator exhausted")
```

with

```
for i in range(5):
    break
else:
    print("Iterator exhausted")
```

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that the idea of such a finalizing clause in a `for` loop is due to Knuth, the choice of `else` as the keyword being that the `break` statement would virtually always guarded by an `if` statement, and the `else` clause being executed if the condition is never executed.  I am not aware of other languages implementing such a feature prior to Python, though, nor can I find a citation for Knuth as the inventor.