# Display all prime numbers within a range

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, range

```
# Write a program to display all prime numbers within a range

start = 25
end = 50

for num in range(start, end + 1):
    if num > 1: # all prime #s are greater than 1
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(num)
```

Why is it that the `else` is written directly under the second `for`?

Is it that it's not necessarily under the `for` but instead, *outside* of the for-loop?
Therefore, running *every* item in the range and checking the ones that are *not* prime in the for-loop as well as the ones that *are* during the `else`?

If that's the case, then why is it that there is break? Doesn't the break immediately stop the entire process and keep the loop ever reaching the `else` statement? Or does it only stop the *current* for-loop-- allowing the `else` statement to run?

I suppose I just need help understanding what's going on.

Comment: In a `for/else`, the `else` part only executes if no `break` is hit in the `for`. In this example, a `break` is hit when the number is not prime, so the `print(num)` doesn't get executed in that case.

Comment: In my case, why is it reaching the `else` if it is definitely hitting the `break` for some non-prime numbers?

Comment: The `else` goes with the inner `for` as does the `break`. Each iteration of the outer `for` loop "resets" the `for/else`.

Comment: oh! That makes so much sense. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 0):

I’m no python expert, but looked it up. You have 2 for loops. This first one iterated the number from start to end. The second one tests if the number (of the first for loop) is a prime. If the number is % i == 0 (The modulo (or "modulus" or "mod") is the remainder after dividing one number by another.) then it’s not a prime number so no print. It breaks the second for loop. And iterates to the next number of the first for loop. If the number is not % i == 0
then it’s a prime number and it will be printed.