# Usage of break in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I am new to programming and I came across these two similar problems:

#### Example 1:

```
for i in range(10):
  if i == 5:
    break
  else:
    print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

#### Example 2:

```
for i in range(5):
    if i == 5:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 Here
```

#### Question:

The second example is executing the else statement also. Why?

Comment: Not sure I get this. You have an else block without a corresponding if statement.

Comment: @righteousness_wealth In Python, `else` doesn't always pair with `if`. It can also go with a `for` or `while` loop, or a `try...except` construction.

Comment: A simple rule to remember: `else:` in a `for` loop means `if no break`. They just did not want to introduce a new keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python use 'else' after for and while loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops)

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

From [this link](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) it explains that for loops can have an else statement.

From the link:

> The else clause executes after the loop completes normally. This means that the loop did not encounter a break statement.

So in your first example the loop hits the break point and so doesn't execute the else clause `print("Here")`. In the second example the last value of `i` in the loop is 4 so the break is never hit.

### Your examples

```py
# Example 1
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        print("Break")
        break
    else:
        print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
# Output: 0 1 2 3 4 Break
    
    
# Example 2 
for i in range(5):
    if i == 5:
        print("Break")
        break
    else:
        print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
    
# Output: 0 1 2 3 4 Here

# Another example that doesn't cause break
for i in range(3):
    if i == 5:
        print("Break")
        break
    else:
        print(i)
else:
    print("Here")
    
# Output: 0 1 2 Here
```

Comment: Thanks... Didn't know a for loop could have an else block in python.

Answer (score 0):

In python, we can use any loop and else. If the loop breaks, then else statement will not be executed. Else will be executed when the loop doesn't break.

For more ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-else-conditional-statement-with-for-loop-in-python/

Correcting post the comment from @Slothrop

Comment: *"If the loop is breaks then else statement will be executed or else no."* The other way round. If the loop is **not** broken, the else statement will be executed. If the loop is broken, the else statement is not executed.

Comment: Yup, the other way round, thanks for correcting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).