# Collection of numbers

Tags: python

Write a program that processes a collection of numbers using a for loop. The program should end immediately, printing only the word "Done", when a zero is encountered (use a break for this). Negative numbers should be ignored (use a continue for this; I know you can also easily do this with a condition, but I want you to practice with continue). If no zero is encountered, the program should display the sum of all numbers (do this in an else clause). Always display "Done" at the end of the program.

I tried the code below :

```
total = 0
for num in ( 12, 4, 3, 33, -2, -5, 7, 0, 22, 4 ):
    if num < 0:
        continue 
    if num == 0:
        print("Done")
        break
    else:
        total += num
        print(total)
if num > 0:
    print(total)
print("D0ne")
```

It  returns:
12
16
19
52
59
Done
D0ne

But With the numbers provided, the program should display only "Done". If you remove the zero, it should display 85 (and "Done").

Comment: `break` causes the program to go to the end of the `for` loop. there it finds a print, and executes it...

Comment: *"do this in an else clause"* - the instructor is probably expecting you to use a `for...else` structure, not `if...else`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979970/why-does-python-use-else-after-for-and-while-loops

Comment: The loop should only be summing the numbers while keeping track of if a zero is encountered by setting a flag and breaking out. Then, after that loop ends, check if the flag is set and print the appropriate output.

Comment: @slothrop, remove the `print` from within the loop...

Comment: "But With the numbers provided, the program should display only "Done"" - to be clear: you think it should **not** run the `print("D0ne")`? Why not? What part of your code do you think should cause that to be skipped, and how do you think that should work? (Hint: what is the indentation of that line? Is it inside of any kind of conditional block or loop? "The program should end immediately, printing only the word "Done", when a zero is encountered (use a break for this)." - this makes no sense; **`break` does not do that**.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 it should be in an `else` clause associated with the `for`, so that it prints if and only if no `break` happens (the requirement is to print the total "if no zero is encountered")

Comment: It should print "D0ne" but not the sum ofnumbers before 0

Comment: @slothrop oh you mean the number print, yea.

Comment: Remove the print from the loop and insert `print("D0ne")` to the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for/else pattern is ideal for this:

```
total = 0
for num in ( 12, 4, 3, 33, -2, -5, 7, 0, 22, 4 ):
    if num < 0:
        continue
    if num == 0:
        break
    total += num
else:
    print(total)
print('Done')
```