# Python Singleton class to handle "MySQL server has gone away" error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, singleton, mysql-python

When I was trying to execute a query -

```
select * from students where id = 20
```

using Python's **MySQLdb** library, I was getting an exception: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError` saying `MySQL server has gone away`. Some of my friends suggested me to use the existing mysql connection. So I started referring [this link](http://natefactorial.com/2009/11/19/python-singletons-a-cool-way/) and used the same **Singleton** class from the link in my code below, it still gives me the same exception.

```
#DBConnect.py
import MySQLdb as connector
from Singleton import Singleton
class DBConnect:
    # As the link suggests
    __metaclass__  = Singleton
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbConnection = connector.Connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', 
                                          passwd = 'root', db = 'school')
        self.dbCursor = self.dbConnection.cursor(cursorclass=connector.cursors.DictCursor) 

    def getRecord(self,query):
        self.dbCursor.execute(query)
        result = self.dbCursor.fetchone()
        return result

    def __del__(self):
        self.dbCursor.close()
        self.dbConnection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dc = DBConnect()
    query = "select * from students where id = 20"
    result = dc.getRecord(query)
```

I have tried to create more instances of **DBConnect** like -

```
dc2 = DBConnect()
dc3 = DBConnect()
```

When I print dc, dc2 and dc3 it gives -

```
<__main__.DBConnect object at 0x8a5fe8c> 
<__main__.DBConnect object at 0x8a5fe8c> 
<__main__.DBConnect object at 0x8a5fe8c>
```

Meaning the same instance. So what seems to be the problem? Why can't I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually the Singleton. Its sole purpose as a singleton is to ensure that only one instance of a class is created. When you use the `__metaclass__ = Singleton` line in your class, you are ensuring that only one instance of `DBConnect` can be created, and that any subsequent instantiations of that class will point back to the same instance. Therefore when you use `dc2 = DBConnect()` and `dc3 = DBConnect()`, you are just referring back to the same instance, hence the same identifier you see.

Here is the part of your Singleton code that is causing the behavior:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kw)

        return self.instance
```

After you create an instance of `DBConnect`, `self.instance` is no longer `None`, meaning that the instance you first created (which gets stored in `self.instance`) is the one that is returned anytime you call your class.

My (unsolicited) advice would be to start from scratch and just try to get a basic connection working with the MySQLdb library - the error you mention up top is indicative of MySQL error, so doing some troubleshooting there may be the best course of action.

Comment: So my problem is not related to singleton?

Comment: @HussainTamboli Right - the initial problem sounds like it is simply not making a connection to MySQL itself. Have you tried re-attempting the connection in the same script?

Comment: Yes. I have been running the DBConnect.py script again and again. so my "__init__" is creating a new connection.

Comment: @Sorry, I meant retrying it without the singleton - just a very basic connector. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567622/is-there-a-pythonic-way-to-try-something-up-to-a-maximum-number-of-times answer for a potential implementation.

Comment: @HussainTamboli That last comment was for you (and I think that means it's bedtime for me :) )

Comment: +1. Good link. but these are just the attempts to connect to the mysql server. How can I get a reliable connection each time I do _getRecord_ . How do I resolve the problem of "mysql has gone away"?

Comment: @HussainTamboli I'll do some more thinking tomorrow, but this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html is the MySQL documentation on the actual error and its causes. It seems that this can be related to a client not having proper permissions (usually that is a different error, but I don't recall the special case in this situation), having certain values for connection variables, or oftentimes it can be that the connection just went idle (connection.ping() was a suggestion there).

Comment: @HussainTamboli I would suggest creating a fresh script and seeing if you can establish a connection with a very basic setup (I.e. straight from the docs). If not, there is likely something going on with the MySQL host.